# CoreData prevent crashing on update

Tags: ios, core-data

I have developed an iOS application. The app uses CoreData and I may update something on CoreData in the future.

I know if any change occurs on CoreData the app will crash (on the device which has the old version) due to changes and it is handled on `AppDelegate`.

To make the app not crash I believe I need some changes on the following methods:

```
func saveContext ()
lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator?
```

These methods call `abort()` function (in default) with the following comment lines:

```
// Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
// abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
```

What should I do before publishing the app to not make it happen to crash for next updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to create a new version of the model :

http://www.raywenderlich.com/27657/how-to-perform-a-lightweight-core-data-migration

After you've make that in place you can also overide the peristentStoreCoordinator method to destroy the database and recreate it in case of extreme bad situation (user lost all his data, but the app start) by adding the code below (objc) instead of just abort it will destroy the database, and create an empty one. It can be usefull in dev, that should be a safeguard in prod but your code should never go there.

```
//delete the store
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:storePath error:nil];
// recreate the store
if (![persistentStoreCoordinator_ addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
```